# Properly escaping a path with spaces in CMD shell

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt, escaping

I have the following path:

> "d:\workspace\Server trunk - CI\make\make & publish.bat"

However, when I try to execute this from a cmd shell, I get the error:

> 'd:\workspace\Server' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to escape those spaces properly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to quote everything bar the extension

```
"d:\workspace\Server trunk - CI\make\make & publish".bat
```

Answer (score 3):

"d:\workspace\Server trunk - CI\make\make" & publish.bat